# Let another user restart VirtualBox machine

Tags: virtualbox, users

I run a VirtualBox VM (with Windows 10 as its guest) under my user account on Ubuntu 14.04.  I'd like to allow other users to reboot or start that VM without giving them any other access to my account.  They need to be able to reboot or start it from the command line.  I need to keep access myself, and I don't want to create a second VM by copying it.

VirtualBox version: 5.1.4r110228

Comment: move or copy the VM to their account.

Comment: If I get right what you want, you could change permissions so that files of the VM would have `rwx` for "other users". Alternatively, allow an `rwx` access there only for specific group, and add the users you want to that group.

Comment: @Hi-Angel That would allow others to read and write to the VM's host files, but how would that help in rebooting a VM that's running or starting a VM that isn't set up in another user's account?

Comment: Now I get what you're talking about. Indeed, I ran a VM as a user, and I didn't see it as a root. I gone through the manual for `VBoxManage`, but didn't find anything relevant. You might probably have a better luck asking specifically at [VB forum](forums.virtualbox.org). I'd recommend to formulate the question like *"`VBoxManage list runningvms` didn't list VMs running as another user"*, the solution would probably involve all other actions as well.